# unable to set Row.Readonly=false in Datagridview in winforms

Tags: winforms

I have a datagridview with its ReadOnly set true to prevent people editing.

then I have a button on each row. when I click on a specific button, I wrote:

```
private void DGGrade_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RowIndex > 0 && e.ColumnIndex == DGGrade.Columns["Edit"].Index)
        {

            DGGrade.Rows[DGGrade.CurrentCell.RowIndex].ReadOnly = false;

            DGGrade.Rows[DGGrade.CurrentCell.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;
        }
```

But it is not working. please help

Comment: Are you sure that the event fires? If the row is readonly iam not sure you can click the button.

Comment: oh, youre right. I want to block all the cells so that people can not edit data unless they have to click the button on the row they want to edit and then the row will be unblocked. How can I do that?

Comment: That seems to be difficult. You could try to handle the Click event of the Grid. Then you have to use GridHitInfo to know the position of the cursor. If the position is in rectangle of the button cell you activate the row. Its a bit dirty because you fake the button more or less but that should be work but iam not able to try it today sorry.

Comment: Otherwise its better if you declare a button on your bar or elsewhere and this button activates the focused row.

Comment: Do you have any questions regarding my answer?

Answer (score 2):

I do not know the reason why it is not working but as far as i can tell from my test runs it has to deal how the data is bound. If you use `dataGridView1.DataSource = GetDataSource();` then it did not work in my tests. I have read once about some of the drawbacks of automated binding but i could not find it. Here is the code that works. A row is only in `EditMode` after the User has clicked the button `Edit` in the corresponding row. I will be back later - let me know if you need more pointers.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int rowIndexOfEditableRow = -1;
    public Form1() {
       InitializeComponent();           
       CreateDataGridView(dataGridView1);
       SetExistingDataGridViewRowsReadOnly();           
       this.dataGridView1.Columns.Add(GetBtnColumn());          
    }

    private void SetExistingDataGridViewRowsReadOnly() {
        DataGridViewRowCollection rows = this.dataGridView1.Rows;
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in rows) {
            row.ReadOnly = true;
        }
    }
```

It seems that the grid must be filled manually - at least this way the change of ReadOnly works

```
public void CreateDataGridView(DataGridView dgv) 
{                   
   dgv.ColumnCount = 3;
   dgv.Columns[0].Name = "Id";
   dgv.Columns[1].Name = "Lastname";
   dgv.Columns[2].Name = "City";
   dgv.BackgroundColor = Color.Gray;                        
   AddRowsToDataGridView(dgv);          
}


private void AddRowsToDataGridView(DataGridView dgv)
{
  string[] row1 = new string[]{"1", "Muller", "Seattle"};
  string[] row2 = new string[]{"2", "Arkan", "Austin"};
  string[] row3 = new string[]{"3", "Cooper", "New York"};        
  object[] rows = new object[] { row1, row2, row3 };

  foreach (string[] rowArray in rows)
  {
    dgv.Rows.Add(rowArray);
  }
}
```

Helper method to create a column with a button

```
    public DataGridViewButtonColumn GetBtnColumn()
    {       
      DataGridViewButtonColumn btnColumn = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
      btnColumn.HeaderText = "Edit";
      btnColumn.Text = "Edit";
      btnColumn.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;            
      return btnColumn;
    }
```

Event handler checks if the user has clicked the edit button. In this case the current row will be set to `ReadOnly = false`. This allows that the user to edit the row. To emphasize it i changed the background color of the row.

```
    private void DataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) 
    {
      int colIndex = e.ColumnIndex;
      int rowIndex = e.RowIndex;
      Type cellType =   dataGridView1.Columns[colIndex].CellType;
      if (cellType == typeof(DataGridViewButtonCell))               
      {
        dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].ReadOnly = false;
        dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.GreenYellow;
        this.rowIndexOfEditableRow = rowIndex;
        label1.Text = rowIndexOfEditableRow.ToString() + " " + colIndex.ToString();
      }             
    }
```

If the Row-leave-Event is fired the style is reset and the global parameter which row is editable is set to the initial value

```
    private void DataGridView1_RowLeave(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) 
    {
      int rowIndex = e.RowIndex;
      dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].ReadOnly = true;
      dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;
      this.rowIndexOfEditableRow = -1;
    }
}
```

The above code contains all (except the designer files) that you need to create this demo:

[image]

Comment: This is a great answer! Do you know if there is any way to make a databound DataGridView row editable? I have been searching for ages and cant seem to find a way